Is it ok to name my game "theme park administrator"?
English is not my primary language so, I'm wondering, is it ok to name my game "Theme park administrator" ?
Would "Theme park universe" be a better name ?

Sure. There's a series called Theme Park Tycoon, and it's a similar idea. However, "Administrator" kinda makes people think of a boring job. "Universe" is defintely better. Some other ideas are:

Theme Park Mogul
Theme Park Boss
Theme Park Billionaire
Theme Park Executive
Theme Park Designer
Theme Park Manager

